# How to send messages to multiple numbers using Arduino uno & SIM800 module?

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm

I am using following code to send message using Arduino Uno & SIM800 module.
But I need to send same message on multiple numbers then what changes should I make in my code.

```
const int buttonPin = 8;   // Main gate sensor 1
const int buttonPin1 = 7;  // Main gate sensor 2
const int buttonPin2 = 9;  // Store room sensor 1
const int buttonPin3 = 10; // Store room sensor 2

bool i = false;
bool j = false;
bool k = false;
bool l = false;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin1, INPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin2, INPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin3, INPUT);

  digitalWrite(buttonPin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(buttonPin1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(buttonPin2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(buttonPin3, LOW);

  delay(1000);
}
void loop()

{
  sensor1();
  sensor2();
}
  void sensor1()
  {
  if (digitalRead(buttonPin1)== LOW && digitalRead(buttonPin) == HIGH  && i == false)

  {
    Serial.println("OK");
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print("AT+CMGF=1\r\n");
    delay(500);
    Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"");
    Serial.print("+91...................");
    Serial.print("\"\r\n");
    delay(2000);
    Serial.print("Main Gate is Closed");
    Serial.write(0x1A);
    delay(1000);
    i = true;
    j = false;

  }

  if (digitalRead(buttonPin)== LOW && digitalRead(buttonPin1) == HIGH &&  j == false)
  {
    Serial.println("OK");
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print("AT+CMGF=1\r\n");
    delay(500);
    Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"");
    Serial.print("+91........................");
    Serial.print("\"\r\n");
    delay(2000);
    Serial.print("Main Gate is open");
    Serial.write(0x1A);
    delay(1000);
    j = true;
    i = false;
  }
  }
  void sensor2()
  {
  if (digitalRead(buttonPin2) == HIGH && digitalRead(buttonPin3)==LOW && k == false)
  {
    Serial.println("OK");
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print("AT+CMGF=1\r\n");
    delay(500);
    Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"");
    Serial.print("+91....................");
    Serial.print("\"\r\n");
    delay(2000);
    Serial.print("Store room is Closed");
    Serial.write(0x1A);
    delay(1000);
    k = true;
    l = false;
  }
  if (digitalRead(buttonPin3) == HIGH &&digitalRead(buttonPin2)== LOW && l == false)
  {
    Serial.println("OK");
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print("AT+CMGF=1\r\n");
    delay(500);
    Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"");
    Serial.print("+91....................");
    Serial.print("\"\r\n");
    delay(2000);
    Serial.print("Store room is Open");
    Serial.write(0x1A);
    delay(1000);
    l = true;
    k = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Write a function that sends any message to any number and call it numerous times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@nilesh just add some delay between two massege

I modified your code check it

```
const int Main1 = 8;
const int Main2 = 9;
const int Store1 = 7;
const int Store2 = 10;
bool i = false;
bool j = false;
bool k = false;
bool l = false;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(Main1, INPUT);
  pinMode(Main2, INPUT);
  pinMode(Store1, INPUT);
  pinMode(Store2, INPUT);

  digitalWrite(Main1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Main2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Store1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Store2, LOW);

  delay(1000);
}
void loop()

{
  sensor1();
  sensor2();
}
void sensor1()
{
  if (digitalRead(Main1) == HIGH && digitalRead(Main2) == LOW && i == false)

  {
    Serial.println("OK");
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print("AT+CMGF=1\r\n");
    delay(500);
    Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"");
    Serial.print("+91-----------");// first number
    Serial.print("\"\r\n");
    delay(2000);
    Serial.print("Main gate closed");
    Serial.write(0x1A);
    delay(5000);
    Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"");
    Serial.print("+91-----------");// Second number
    Serial.print("\"\r\n");
    delay(2000);
    Serial.print("Main gate closed");
    Serial.write(0x1A);
    delay(1000);
    i = true;
    j = false;

  }
  if (digitalRead(Main2) == HIGH && digitalRead(Main1) == LOW && j == false)
  {
    Serial.println("OK");
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print("AT+CMGF=1\r\n");
    delay(500);
    Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"");
    Serial.print("+91---------------");//first number
    Serial.print("\"\r\n");
    delay(2000);
    Serial.print("Main gate Open");
    Serial.write(0x1A);
    delay(5000);
    Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"");
    Serial.print("+91--------------"); second number
    Serial.print("\"\r\n");
    delay(2000);
    Serial.print("Main gate Open");
    Serial.write(0x1A);
    delay(1000);
    j = true;
    i = false;
  }
}
void sensor2()
{
  if (digitalRead(Store1) == HIGH && digitalRead(Store2) == LOW && k == false)
  {
    Serial.println("OK");
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print("AT+CMGF=1\r\n");
    delay(500);
    Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"");
   Serial.print("+91-----------");// first number
    Serial.print("\"\r\n");
    delay(2000);
    Serial.print("Store room is closed");
    Serial.write(0x1A);
    delay(10000);
    Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"");
    Serial.print("+91-----------");// second number
    Serial.print("\"\r\n");
    delay(2000);
    Serial.print("Store room is Closed");
    Serial.write(0x1A);
    delay(1000);
    k = true;
    l = false;
  }
  if (digitalRead(Store2) == HIGH && digitalRead(Store1) == LOW && l == false)
  {
    Serial.println("OK");
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print("AT+CMGF=1\r\n");
    delay(500);
    Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"");
   Serial.print("+91-----------");// first number
    Serial.print("\"\r\n");
    delay(2000);
    Serial.print("Store room is Open");
    Serial.write(0x1A);
    delay(5000);
    Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"");
   Serial.print("+91-----------");// Second number
    Serial.print("\"\r\n");
    delay(2000);
    Serial.print("Store room is Open");
    Serial.write(0x1A);
    delay(1000);
    l = true;
    k = false;
  }
}
```

thanks

bhupendra.sinkar727@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

I have same question but minor different.

sim.println("AT+CMGS="+91xxxxxxxxxx"\r");

i dont want to write this. i want to write mobile number on serial monitor in arduino and on that number, i want to send message. how can i do?

Answer (score -1):

Try out this one. Here, I made the code for two number. Just simply add a new function for every new number. I hope it will help you.

```
const int buttonPin = 8;   // Main gate sensor 1
const int buttonPin1 = 7;  // Main gate sensor 2
const int buttonPin2 = 9;  // Store room sensor 1
const int buttonPin3 = 10; // Store room sensor 2

bool i = false;
bool j = false;
bool k = false;
bool l = false;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin1, INPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin2, INPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin3, INPUT);

  digitalWrite(buttonPin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(buttonPin1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(buttonPin2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(buttonPin3, LOW);

  delay(1000);
}
void loop()

{
  sensor1();
  sensor2();
}

void sensor1()
{
  if (digitalRead(buttonPin1)== LOW && digitalRead(buttonPin) == HIGH  && i == false)
  {
    numOneGateClose();
    numTwoGateClose();
    i = true;
    j = false;
  }

  if (digitalRead(buttonPin)== LOW && digitalRead(buttonPin1) == HIGH &&  j == false)
  {
   numOneGateOpen();
   numTwoGateOpen();
    j = true;
    i = false;
  }
}

void sensor2()
{
  if (digitalRead(buttonPin2) == HIGH && digitalRead(buttonPin3)==LOW && k == false)
  {
    numOneRoomClose();
    numTwoRoomClose();
    k = true;
    l = false;
  }

  if (digitalRead(buttonPin3) == HIGH &&digitalRead(buttonPin2)== LOW && l == false)
  {
    numOneRoomOpen();
    numTwoRoomOpen();
    l = true;
    k = false;
  }
}

void numOneGateClose()
{
  Serial.println("OK");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("AT+CMGF=1\r\n");
  delay(500);
  Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"");
  Serial.print("+91...................");
  Serial.print("\"\r\n");
  delay(2000);
  Serial.print("Main Gate is Closed");
  Serial.write(0x1A);
  delay(1000);
}

void numTwoGateClose()
{
  Serial.println("OK");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("AT+CMGF=1\r\n");
  delay(500);
  Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"");
  Serial.print("+91...................");
  Serial.print("\"\r\n");
  delay(2000);
  Serial.print("Main Gate is Closed");
  Serial.write(0x1A);
  delay(1000);
}

void numOneGateOpen()
{
  Serial.println("OK");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("AT+CMGF=1\r\n");
  delay(500);
  Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"");
  Serial.print("+91........................");
  Serial.print("\"\r\n");
  delay(2000);
  Serial.print("Main Gate is open");
  Serial.write(0x1A);
  delay(1000);
}

void numTwoGateOpen()
{
  Serial.println("OK");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("AT+CMGF=1\r\n");
  delay(500);
  Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"");
  Serial.print("+91........................");
  Serial.print("\"\r\n");
  delay(2000);
  Serial.print("Main Gate is open");
  Serial.write(0x1A);
  delay(1000);
}

void numOneRoomClose()
{
  Serial.println("OK");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("AT+CMGF=1\r\n");
  delay(500);
  Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"");
  Serial.print("+91...................");
  Serial.print("\"\r\n");
  delay(2000);
  Serial.print("Main Gate is Closed");
  Serial.write(0x1A);
  delay(1000);
}

void numTwoRoomClose()
{
  Serial.println("OK");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("AT+CMGF=1\r\n");
  delay(500);
  Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"");
  Serial.print("+91...................");
  Serial.print("\"\r\n");
  delay(2000);
  Serial.print("Main Gate is Closed");
  Serial.write(0x1A);
  delay(1000);
}

void numOneRoomOpen()
{
  Serial.println("OK");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("AT+CMGF=1\r\n");
  delay(500);
  Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"");
  Serial.print("+91........................");
  Serial.print("\"\r\n");
  delay(2000);
  Serial.print("Main Gate is open");
  Serial.write(0x1A);
  delay(1000);
}

void numTwoRoomOpen()
{
  Serial.println("OK");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("AT+CMGF=1\r\n");
  delay(500);
  Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"");
  Serial.print("+91........................");
  Serial.print("\"\r\n");
  delay(2000);
  Serial.print("Main Gate is open");
  Serial.write(0x1A);
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: I would like to point out, that there really should be SEND MESSAGE method that would make the whole script shorter and easier to debug. Basic REUSE principle in programming.

Comment: it send message  to only first number

Comment: @NileshSurwade Have you write a different number on both functions? means you have to add different number in `numOneSensor1()` and `numTwoSensor1()`. And same things for `numOneSensor2()` and `numTwoSensor2()`

Comment: Lead by example. That code isn't a good example. As @Divisadero says, write a SEND MESSAGE function and reuse it many times.

Comment: @ Hasan sir, I added two different number in numOneSensor1() and numTwoSensor1(). And i done same thing for numOneSensor2() and numTwoSensor2(). But it does not work it only send massage on first number. Please help.

Comment: @NileshSurwade Ok, let me check and update my code again.

Comment: @NileshSurwade I update my code. I hope it will help.