# Send message to multiple number

Tags: arduino-uno, c, communication, gsm, iot

`sim.println("AT+CMGS=\"+91xxxxxxxxxx\"\r");`

I don't want to write this. I want to write mobile number on serial monitor in Arduino and on that number, i want to send message. how can I do?

Comment: I changed the qs for you, hope I made the right corrections!

Comment: @SomasundharamSampath Where did you get the information for your edit of the question? Have I missed something here?

Comment: @Mehul What exactly is your problem with this? Is it about the serial communication? Or is it about putting together the received number for sending to the GSM module? What have you tried so far? Have you looked at some of the many examples and tutorials about serial communication?

Comment: I saw this comment/ answer  https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/78443/11957

Comment: Actually, there are different different number which may don't know every time.
Every time i change number and install on board that is not possible. so i want to make code in which write number and send same message on it.